# Correct way to 301 redirect from one domain to new domain with a new url structure?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, seo

We are moving a directory from one domain to a new domain. We will be using permanent 301 redirects to do this for SEO purposes. We will also be changing our url naming scheme. This will need to apply to several hundred pages. Trying to figure out the regex / 301 to accomplish the following. Never done this before so I really want to make sure I don't get this wrong.

```
olddomain.com/doctor_directory/City_State_type_doctor.html

newdomain.com/doctor_directory/city-state-type-doctor.html
```

- new domain urls are changed to all **lowercase**
- new domain filenames now use a **hyphens instead of underscores**

Thanks in advance to anyone can help with the most efficient reg ex to accomplish this!

Reference:
http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection

Comment: Thanks Abhishek! Could you please provide an example in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)_([^/]*)$ $1-$2 [QSA,N]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*\.|)olddomain.com:(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http%3://${lc:%1}newdomain.com/${lc:$1} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ωmega, thats awesome. If it is not possible within .htaccess where/how should what you provided be implemented?

Comment: @chainwork - It is possible using flag `[N]`, which causes the ruleset to start over again from the top, using the result of the ruleset so far as a starting point. Use with extreme caution, as it may result in loop. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks Ωmega! Would it make it any less risky if the url changes were only applied to the html filename and not to the directory /doctor_directory/ ? Our other option is to leave the url structure exactly the same if what we are trying to do is too risky.

Comment: @chainwork - Risky is to make it work. Once redirection works, then it is not risky anymore :) I have updated my answer with solution where character replacement apply just to filenames, not directories. Is that what you want, to keep directory names unchanged?